# how to compare two dictionaries which has two different count values to check pk and update the main dictionary and retrieve when table reloads

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, compare

I have two arrays with different count values same as below

```
Main array -  var productArray = [[String: Any]]() "greater count values than cart array"
Sub Array -  var cartArray = [[String: Any]]()  "less count values and some times empty"
```

These are the response of the following arrays

```
 Product Array:: [["pk": 5277, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5281, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5287, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5292, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5298, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5303, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5304, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5309, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5313, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5319, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 4859, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 4867, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 7998, "quantity": 0]]

    Cart Array:: [["pk": 5298, "quantity": 3], ["pk": 7998, "quantity": 3], ["pk": 8046, "quantity": 1]]
```

I just want to compare both and if both array's pk is same i just want update the product array with the cart array's pk. like below for example..

```
Product Array:: [["pk": 5277, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5281, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5287, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5292, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5298, "quantity": 3], ["pk": 5303, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5304, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5309, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5313, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 5319, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 4859, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 4867, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 7998, "quantity": 0]]
```

"common value is 5298 here"

please help me in a clear latest swift code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check below codes :

```
var productArray: [[String: Any]] = [
    [
        "pk": 1,
        "quantity": 0
    ],
    [
        "pk": 2,
        "quantity": 0
    ],
    [
        "pk": 3,
        "quantity": 0
    ],
    [
        "pk": 4,
        "quantity": 0
    ]
]

let chartArray: [[String: Any]] = [
    [
        "pk": 1,
        "quantity": 100
    ],
    [
        "pk": 2,
        "quantity": 100
    ],
    [
        "pk": 3,
        "quantity": 100
    ]
]

productArray = productArray.compactMap({ (product: [String: Any]) -> [String : Any]? in

    for chart in chartArray {

        guard let chartQuantity = chart["pk"] as? Int,
            let chartPK = chart["pk"] as? Int,
            let productPK = product["pk"] as? Int,
            chartPK == productPK else {
                continue
        } // pass if have same pk value

        return [
            "pk": chartPK,
            "quantity": chartQuantity
        ]
    }

    return product
})

print(productArray.description)
```